# shellscript: read csv and print as string doesn't work as expected

Tags: shell

I'm reading a single-cell csv file and printing the value as a string with some other strings attached to it. It does not work for certain combinations. Do you know why?

```
 while IFS="," read ts
 do
     echo "timestamp is: $
     tstamp=$ts
 done < timestamp.csv

 a="TS_"
 c="234"
 b=".log"
 d="${a}${c}${b}"
 Log_1="${a}$tstamp"
 Log_2="${tstamp}${a}"
 echo "$d"
 echo "$Log_1"
 echo "$Log_2"
```

actual result:

```
timestamp is: 0x5cff71d8

TS_234.log

TS_0x5cff71d8

TS_cff71d8
```

expected result:

```
timestamp is: 0x5cff71d8

TS_234.log

TS_0x5cff71d8

0x5cff71d8TS_
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSV file was made on a Windows machine and each line ends with a CR (`'\r'`, `'\x0D'`) character followed by a LF (`'\n'`, `'\x0A'`) character; you are reading the file on a Linux or Unix or MacOS machine, where lines are supposed to end with a bare LF character.

CR is Carriage Return: printing this character moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line.

Your `$Log_2` variable contains `0` `x` `5` `c` `f` `f` `7` `1` `d` `8` `\r` `T` `S` `_`, which, when printed looks like `TS_cff71d8`:

`0x5cff71d8\r` (now cursor moves back to the beginning of the line)
`TS_` (overwriting the first three characters)

To check, try `echo "$Log_2" | od -A x -t x1z -v` (or whatever options for `od` work on your system).

To get rid of the MS-DOS-ish CR characters, you may have a utility on your system named [`dos2unix`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/dos2unix.1.html); or you may try `sed -e 's/\r//g'`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tested the "sed" and it works.